# Yii relations and findAllByAttributes

Tags: php, yii

In order to find all records with a given quantity I have the following code.  This is giving me the proper records back but it only shows the 'id' of each record.  How can I display 'AttributeB' instead of 'id' in my results.

```
$qty = $model->relation->Quantity;
$item = ModelB::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('Quantity'=>$qty));

echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'Attribute', $item);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
echo $form->dropDownList($model,'Attribute',CHtml::listData($item, 'id', 'attributeB'));
```